# Как передать в скрипт на python несколько значений переменных?

Tags: python, json, python-3.6, zabbix

Стоит задача распарсить json файл со сложной внутренней структурой и некоторые значения передать через агента в Zabbix. Написал на питон парсер, который обрабатывает этот файл, но уровень решения меня не устраивает.

Подскажите как можно отправить в скрипт несколько значений, которые будут ключами сформированного словаря и на выходе получить запрошенное значение которое потом можно передать. Пример кода:

```
    `import json
     path = 'file'
     with open(path,'r') as f:
         data = json.loads(f.read())
         active= data['connections']['active']
     print (active)`
```

Вместо 'connections' и 'active' извне передать праметры которые будут ключами в текущем словаре.
Пример json:

`{"hostName":"localdomain","nginxVersion":"1.12.2","loadMsec":1523646344246,"nowMsec":1524228225225,"connections":{"active":89,"reading":0,"writing":9,"waiting":80,"accepted":355871,"handled":355871,"requests":3213643},"sharedZones":{"name":"ngx_http_vhost_traffic_status","maxSize":1048575,"usedSize":24603,"usedNode":10},"serverZones":{"localhost":{"requestCounter":3208550,"inBytes":44896968109,"outBytes":32102485944,"responses":{"1xx":0,"2xx":2951739,"3xx":164006,"4xx":5599,"5xx":87206,"miss":0,"bypass":0,"expired":0,"stale":0,"updating":0,"revalidated":0,"hit":0,"scarce":0},"requestMsec":37,"requestMsecs":{"times":[1524228222089,1524228222092,1524228222175,1524228222199,1524228222241,1524228222274,1524228222326,1524228222336,1524228222350,1524228222489,1524228222578,1524228222701,1524228222735,1524228222873,1524228222963,1524228222999,1524228223089,1524228223120,1524228223142,1524228223166,1524228223249,1524228223377,1524228223414,1524228223586,1524228223608,1524228223632,1524228223680,1524228223755,1524228223793,1524228223893,1524228223925,1524228224000,1524228224045,1524228224148,1524228224169,1524228224248,1524228224286,1524228224333,1524228224339,1524228224347,1524228224357,1524228224360,1524228224378,1524228224432,1524228224478,1524228224490,1524228224523,1524228224530,1524228224556,1524228224564,1524228224580,1524228224651,1524228224669,1524228224694,1524228224799,1524228224812,1524228224819,1524228224944,1524228225001,1524228225037,1524228225092,1524228225180,1524228225188],"msecs":[3,2,6,1,0,1,1,1,1,2,7,2,2,2,9,0,1,3,1,8,1,26,1,3,1,31,1,1758,3,8,2,0,2,1,2,4,8,2,1,6,3,1,1,2,1,3,6,2,5,5,1,7,1,238,1,127,1,2,0,12,2,1,1]},"overCounts":{"maxIntegerSize":18446744073709551615,"requestCounter":0,"inBytes":0,"outBytes":0,"1xx":0,"2xx":0,"3xx":0,"4xx":0,"5xx":0,"miss":0,"bypass":0,"expired":0,"stale":0,"updating":0,"revalidated":0,"hit":0,"scarce":0}},"*":{"requestCounter":3208550,"inBytes":44896968109,"outBytes":32102485944,"responses":{"1xx":0,"2xx":2951739,"3xx":164006,"4xx":5599,"5xx":87206,"miss":0,"bypass":0,"expired":0,"stale":0,"updating":0,"revalidated":0,"hit":0,"scarce":0},"requestMsec":18,"requestMsecs":{"times":[1524228225188,1524228222059,1524228222089,1524228222092,1524228222175,1524228222199,1524228222241,1524228222274,1524228222326,1524228222336,1524228222350,1524228222489,1524228222578,1524228222701,1524228222735,1524228222873,1524228222963,1524228222999,1524228223089,1524228223120,1524228223142,1524228223166,1524228223249,1524228223377,1524228223414,1524228223586,1524228223608,1524228223632,1524228223680,1524228223755,1524228223793,1524228223893,1524228223925,1524228224000,1524228224045,1524228224148,1524228224169,1524228224248,1524228224286,1524228224333,1524228224339,1524228224347,1524228224357,1524228224360,1524228224378,1524228224432,1524228224478,1524228224490,1524228224523,1524228224530,1524228224556,1524228224564,1524228224580,1524228224651,1524228224669,1524228224694,1524228224799,1524228224812,1524228224819,1524228224944,1524228225001,1524228225037,1524228225092],"msecs":[1,1,2,1,3,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,4,1,1,1,5,0,1,2,1,4,1,13,1,2,1,16,1,879,2,4,1,0,1,1,1,2,4,1,1,3,2,1,1,1,1,2,3,1,3,3,1,4,1,119,1,64,1,1,0,6,1]},"overCounts":{"maxIntegerSize":18446744073709551615,"requestCounter":0,"inBytes":0,"outBytes":0,"1xx":0,"2xx":0,"3xx":0,"4xx":0,"5xx":0,"miss":0,"bypass":0,"expired":0,"stale":0,"updating":0,"revalidated":0,"hit":0,"scarce":0}}},"upstreamZones":{"service":[{"server":"127.0.0.1:8081","requestCounter":451833,"inBytes":581218026,"outBytes":2829724049,"responses":{"1xx":0,"2xx":403537,"3xx":47016,"4xx":1268,"5xx":12},"requestMsec":5,"requestMsecs":{"times":[1524228217927,1524228218099,1524228218202,1524228218376,1524228218467,1524228218646,1524228218809,1524228218898,1524228219070,1524228219169,1524228219266,1524228219436,1524228219528,1524228219617,1524228219788,1524228219897,1524228219987,1524228220153,1524228220257,1524228220347,1524228220520,1524228220625,1524228220747,1524228220908,1524228221009,1524228221098,1524228221255,1524228221353,1524228221442,1524228221605,1524228221720,1524228221808,1524228221971,1524228222059,1524228222089,1524228222092,1524228222175,1524228222199,1524228222241,1524228222274,1524228222336,1524228222350,1524228222489,1524228222578,1524228222735,1524228222873,1524228222963,1524228223120,1524228223249,1524228223377,1524228223608,1524228223793,1524228223893,1524228224045,1524228224169,1524228224286,1524228224432,1524228224564,1524228224651,1524228224799,1524228224944,1524228225037,1524228225188],"msecs":[73,2,21,2,7,3,2,8,2,2,15,2,1,7,1,2,10,2,2,10,2,2,7,2,2,9,2,2,7,2,1,7,3,1,3,2,6,1,0,1,1,1,2,7,2,2,9,3,1,26,1,3,8,2,2,8,2,5,7,1,2,12,1]},"responseMsec":5,"responseMsecs":{"times":[1524228217927,1524228218099,1524228218202,1524228218376,1524228218467,1524228218646,1524228218809,1524228218898,1524228219070,1524228219169,1524228219266,1524228219436,1524228219528,1524228219617,1524228219788,1524228219897,1524228219987,1524228220153,1524228220257,1524228220347,1524228220520,1524228220625,1524228220747,1524228220908,1524228221009,1524228221098,1524228221255,1524228221353,1524228221442,1524228221605,1524228221720,1524228221808,1524228221971,1524228222059,1524228222089,1524228222092,1524228222175,1524228222199,1524228222241,1524228222274,1524228222336,1524228222350,1524228222489,1524228222578,1524228222735,1524228222873,1524228222963,1524228223120,1524228223249,1524228223377,1524228223608,1524228223793,1524228223893,1524228224045,1524228224169,1524228224286,1524228224432,1524228224564,1524228224651,1524228224799,1524228224944,1524228225037,1524228225188],"msecs":[73,2,21,2,7,3,2,8,2,2,15,2,1,7,1,2,10,2,2,10,2,2,7,2,2,9,2,2,7,2,1,7,3,1,3,2,6,1,0,1,1,1,2,7,2,2,9,3,1,26,1,3,8,2,2,8,2,5,7,1,2,12,1]},"weight":10,"maxFails":1,"failTimeout":600,"backup":false,"down":false,"overCounts":{"maxIntegerSize":18446744073709551615,"requestCounter":0,"inBytes":0,"outBytes":0,"1xx":0,"2xx":0,"3xx":0,"4xx":0,"5xx":0}},{"server":"127.0.0.1:8082","requestCounter":685202,"inBytes":715101609,"outBytes":3998823685,"responses":{"1xx":0,"2xx":635269,"3xx":48465,"4xx":1458,"5xx":10},"requestMsec":9550,"requestMsecs":{"times":[1524228210598,1524228210697,1524228210715,1524228210756,1524228210837,1524228211084,1524228211630,1524228211651,1524228211729,1524228211904,1524228212050,1524228212470,1524228212498,1524228212540,1524228212907,1524228213061,1524228213104,1524228213560,1524228214061,1524228214347,1524228214504,1524228214981,1524228215175,1524228215923,1524228215942,1524228215969,1524228216080,1524228216494,1524228216573,1524228216592,1524228216714,1524228216895,1524228217095,1524228217096,1524228217369,1524228217442,1524228218008,1524228220423,1524228220466,1524228220572,1524228220628,1524228220754,1524228220803,1524228221627,1524228221775,1524228221819,1524228222055,1524228222326,1524228223142,1524228223166,1524228223414,1524228223680,1524228224333,1524228224339,1524228224347,1524228224357,1524228224478,1524228224530,1524228224556,1524228224669,1524228224812,1524228225092,1524228225180],"msecs":[2,85,2,2,3,27,1,2,1,1,1,1,8,1,2,2,8,1,2,1,1,608,2,1,1,1,9,2,1,8,2,299,1,312,3,1,1,1,1,66,47,1,2,600002,2,5,2,1,1,8,1,1,2,1,6,3,1,2,5,1,127,2,1]},"responseMsec":9549,"responseMsecs":{"times":[1524228210598,1524228210697,1524228210715,1524228210756,1524228210837,1524228211084,1524228211630,1524228211651,1524228211729,1524228211904,1524228212050,1524228212470,1524228212498,1524228212540,1524228212907,1524228213061,1524228213104,1524228213560,1524228214061,1524228214347,1524228214504,1524228214981,1524228215175,1524228215923,1524228215942,1524228215969,1524228216080,1524228216494,1524228216573,1524228216592,1524228216714,1524228216895,1524228217095,1524228217096,1524228217369,1524228217442,1524228218008,1524228220423,1524228220466,1524228220572,1524228220628,1524228220754,1524228220803,1524228221627,1524228221775,1524228221819,1524228222055,1524228222326,1524228223142,1524228223166,1524228223414,1524228223680,1524228224333,1524228224339,1524228224347,1524228224357,1524228224478,1524228224530,1524228224556,1524228224669,1524228224812,1524228225092,1524228225180],"msecs":[2,41,2,2,3,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,8,1,2,2,8,1,2,1,1,608,2,1,1,1,9,2,1,8,2,299,1,312,3,1,1,1,1,66,47,1,2,600002,2,5,2,1,1,8,1,1,2,1,6,3,1,2,5,1,127,2,1]},"weight":10,"maxFails":1,"failTimeout":600,"backup":false,"down":false,"overCounts":{"maxIntegerSize":18446744073709551615,"requestCounter":0,"inBytes":0,"outBytes":0,"1xx":0,"2xx":0,"3xx":0,"4xx":0,"5xx":0}},{"server":"127.0.0.1:8083","requestCounter":563868,"inBytes":818776762,"outBytes":3664324284,"responses":{"1xx":0,"2xx":529775,"3xx":32844,"4xx":1241,"5xx":8},"requestMsec":72,"requestMsecs":{"times":[1524228197487,1524228197534,1524228198493,1524228198748,1524228202226,1524228202373,1524228202751,1524228202805,1524228202960,1524228203111,1524228203388,1524228203393,1524228203400,1524228203539,1524228204630,1524228204714,1524228204774,1524228205469,1524228206232,1524228206450,1524228206832,1524228207164,1524228211013,1524228211109,1524228211242,1524228211395,1524228211786,1524228211953,1524228211995,1524228212497,1524228212621,1524228212865,1524228212879,1524228212895,1524228212913,1524228213008,1524228213385,1524228213631,1524228214136,1524228217258,1524228217402,1524228217520,1524228218076,1524228218473,1524228218610,1524228218863,1524228219577,1524228219908,1524228220422,1524228220812,1524228221279,1524228221559,1524228221885,1524228222701,1524228223089,1524228223586,1524228223632,1524228223925,1524228224360,1524228224378,1524228224523,1524228224694,1524228224819],"msecs":[124,2,409,3,3,37,2,5,48,2,2,1,2,4,1,3,2,2,2,1,1,502,1,6,45,2,2,46,286,44,46,10,1,1,2,45,241,44,2,45,45,1,2,44,47,2,2,5,49,276,9,10,1780,2,1,3,31,2,1,1,6,238,1]},"responseMsec":59,"responseMsecs":{"times":[1524228197487,1524228197534,1524228198493,1524228198748,1524228202226,1524228202373,1524228202751,1524228202805,1524228202960,1524228203111,1524228203388,1524228203393,1524228203400,1524228203539,1524228204630,1524228204714,1524228204774,1524228205469,1524228206232,1524228206450,1524228206832,1524228207164,1524228211013,1524228211109,1524228211242,1524228211395,1524228211786,1524228211953,1524228211995,1524228212497,1524228212621,1524228212865,1524228212879,1524228212895,1524228212913,1524228213008,1524228213385,1524228213631,1524228214136,1524228217258,1524228217402,1524228217520,1524228218076,1524228218473,1524228218610,1524228218863,1524228219577,1524228219908,1524228220422,1524228220812,1524228221279,1524228221559,1524228221885,1524228222701,1524228223089,1524228223586,1524228223632,1524228223925,1524228224360,1524228224378,1524228224523,1524228224694,1524228224819],"msecs":[124,2,409,3,3,37,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,4,1,3,2,2,2,1,1,502,1,2,2,2,2,2,286,1,2,10,1,1,2,2,29,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,5,2,207,2,2,1780,2,1,3,19,2,1,1,6,238,1]},"weight":10,"maxFails":1,"failTimeout":600,"backup":false,"down":false,"overCounts":{"maxIntegerSize":18446744073709551615,"requestCounter":0,"inBytes":0,"outBytes":0,"1xx":0,"2xx":0,"3xx":0,"4xx":0,"5xx":0}},{"server":"127.0.0.1:8084","requestCounter":493033,"inBytes":683727633,"outBytes":3125030680,"responses":{"1xx":0,"2xx":455846,"3xx":35677,"4xx":1498,"5xx":12},"requestMsec":1071,"requestMsecs":{"times":[1524228198351,1524228198704,1524228199124,1524228199327,1524228199507,1524228199654,1524228200248,1524228200327,1524228200377,1524228200858,1524228200870,1524228200958,1524228201216,1524228201779,1524228201873,1524228202173,1524228202538,1524228202549,1524228203330,1524228203352,1524228204442,1524228204467,1524228204684,1524228204803,1524228204804,1524228205170,1524228205598,1524228206053,1524228206060,1524228206467,1524228207583,1524228207594,1524228208087,1524228209387,1524228209861,1524228209975,1524228210234,1524228210662,1524228211572,1524228211663,1524228212071,1524228212538,1524228214099,1524228214467,1524228216023,1524228216162,1524228216426,1524228217094,1524228220155,1524228220268,1524228220944,1524228221435,1524228221640,1524228221648,1524228221666,1524228221693,1524228221790,1524228221958,1524228223755,1524228224148,1524228224248,1524228224490,1524228224580],"msecs":[3,3,2,1,2,8,1,58,33,1,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,3,2,2,2,39168,1,8,1,1,0,2,6136,4538,1,4,1,2,2,1,3,867,4617,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,10218,3,1,2,2,1,1,1,1758,1,4,3,1]},"responseMsec":1069,"responseMsecs":{"times":[1524228198351,1524228198704,1524228199124,1524228199327,1524228199507,1524228199654,1524228200248,1524228200327,1524228200377,1524228200858,1524228200870,1524228200958,1524228201216,1524228201779,1524228201873,1524228202173,1524228202538,1524228202549,1524228203330,1524228203352,1524228204442,1524228204467,1524228204684,1524228204803,1524228204804,1524228205170,1524228205598,1524228206053,1524228206060,1524228206467,1524228207583,1524228207594,1524228208087,1524228209387,1524228209861,1524228209975,1524228210234,1524228210662,1524228211572,1524228211663,1524228212071,1524228212538,1524228214099,1524228214467,1524228216023,1524228216162,1524228216426,1524228217094,1524228220155,1524228220268,1524228220944,1524228221435,1524228221640,1524228221648,1524228221666,1524228221693,1524228221790,1524228221958,1524228223755,1524228224148,1524228224248,1524228224490,1524228224580],"msecs":[3,3,2,1,2,8,1,2,33,1,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,3,2,2,2,39099,1,2,1,1,0,2,6136,4538,1,4,1,2,2,1,3,867,4617,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,10218,3,1,2,2,1,1,1,1758,1,4,3,1]},"weight":10,"maxFails":1,"failTimeout":600,"backup":false,"down":false,"overCounts":{"maxIntegerSize":18446744073709551615,"requestCounter":0,"inBytes":0,"outBytes":0,"1xx":0,"2xx":0,"3xx":0,"4xx":0,"5xx":0}}],"service2":[{"server":"127.0.0.1:8081","requestCounter":49580,"inBytes":10388295026,"outBytes":41257758,"responses":{"1xx":0,"2xx":27664,"3xx":3,"4xx":4,"5xx":21909},"requestMsec":0,"requestMsecs":{"times":[1524227354971,1524227356367,1524227520955,1524227521551,1524227522875,1524227523611,1524227524556,1524227525538,1524227526337,1524227526713,1524227527082,1524227527797,1524227528286,1524227528749,1524227529337,1524227530331,1524227530818,1524227531254,1524227532253,1524227532941,1524227533472,1524227534164,1524227761247,1524227761636,1524227762835,1524227763726,1524227764397,1524227765666,1524227766272,1524227766719,1524227766995,1524227767561,1524227768151,1524227768689,1524227769265,1524227770082,1524227771070,1524227771573,1524227772659,1524227772984,1524227773991,1524227774692,1524227775808,1524227776556,1524228002640,1524228003313,1524228004297,1524228005266,1524228005683,1524228006043,1524228006318,1524228007017,1524228007515,1524228008013,1524228008684,1524228009723,1524228010227,1524228010660,1524228011668,1524228012468,1524228013111,1524228013794,1524228014883],"msecs":[34,37,62,30,223,34,183,213,28,32,23,44,53,38,51,359,46,30,28,31,22,334,53,23,228,32,30,238,28,29,27,209,46,47,44,56,34,38,606,29,197,41,146,369,261,31,196,196,34,27,21,43,39,40,53,377,36,27,27,31,25,292,65]},"responseMsec":0,"responseMsecs":{"times":[1524227354971,1524227356367,1524227520955,1524227521551,1524227522875,1524227523611,1524227524556,1524227525538,1524227526337,1524227526713,1524227527082,1524227527797,1524227528286,1524227528749,1524227529337,1524227530331,1524227530818,1524227531254,1524227532253,1524227532941,1524227533472,1524227534164,1524227761247,1524227761636,1524227762835,1524227763726,1524227764397,1524227765666,1524227766272,1524227766719,1524227766995,1524227767561,1524227768151,1524227768689,1524227769265,1524227770082,1524227771070,1524227771573,1524227772659,1524227772984,1524227773991,1524227774692,1524227775808,1524227776556,1524228002640,1524228003313,1524228004297,1524228005266,1524228005683,1524228006043,1524228006318,1524228007017,1524228007515,1524228008013,1524228008684,1524228009723,1524228010227,1524228010660,1524228011668,1524228012468,1524228013111,1524228013794,1524228014883],"msecs":[30,36,61,25,219,29,179,208,24,24,22,38,47,32,44,355,40,25,27,27,21,329,52,22,224,28,26,234,24,25,26,203,40,42,37,50,28,34,600,27,193,36,142,365,257,27,193,191,30,26,20,38,33,33,38,372,30,23,26,27,24,287,64]},"weight":10,"maxFails":1,"failTimeout":600,"backup":false,"down":false,"overCounts":{"maxIntegerSize":18446744073709551615,"requestCounter":0,"inBytes":0,"outBytes":0,"1xx":0,"2xx":0,"3xx":0,"4xx":0,"5xx":0}},{"server":"127.0.0.1:8082","requestCounter":49531,"inBytes":10444349658,"outBytes":41388179,"responses":{"1xx":0,"2xx":28080,"3xx":1,"4xx":0,"5xx":21450},"requestMsec":0,"requestMsecs":{"times":[1524227521025,1524227522117,1524227523260,1524227523917,1524227524852,1524227525719,1524227526459,1524227526813,1524227527212,1524227527910,1524227528404,1524227528889,1524227529441,1524227530443,1524227530930,1524227531362,1524227532323,1524227533057,1524227533539,1524227534466,1524227761330,1524227762016,1524227762949,1524227763842,1524227764733,1524227765784,1524227766380,1524227766783,1524227767063,1524227767780,1524227768305,1524227768816,1524227769372,1524227770222,1524227771204,1524227771695,1524227772745,1524227773467,1524227774118,1524227774809,1524227775894,1524228000898,1524228001132,1524228001956,1524228002973,1524228003609,1524228004611,1524228005375,1524228005800,1524228006105,1524228006440,1524228007145,1524228007640,1524228008157,1524228008827,1524228009856,1524228010337,1524228010785,1524228011754,1524228012638,1524228013193,1524228014212,1524228015308],"msecs":[27,476,309,213,201,97,28,20,47,36,38,69,32,32,38,32,22,39,24,215,42,307,37,39,243,31,31,22,25,61,45,45,30,45,55,40,27,403,52,41,42,55,25,274,253,226,240,36,44,21,42,52,47,71,46,52,32,36,33,92,32,315,340]},"responseMsec":0,"responseMsecs":{"times":[1524227521025,1524227522117,1524227523260,1524227523917,1524227524852,1524227525719,1524227526459,1524227526813,1524227527212,1524227527910,1524227528404,1524227528889,1524227529441,1524227530443,1524227530930,1524227531362,1524227532323,1524227533057,1524227533539,1524227534466,1524227761330,1524227762016,1524227762949,1524227763842,1524227764733,1524227765784,1524227766380,1524227766783,1524227767063,1524227767780,1524227768305,1524227768816,1524227769372,1524227770222,1524227771204,1524227771695,1524227772745,1524227773467,1524227774118,1524227774809,1524227775894,1524228000898,1524228001132,1524228001956,1524228002973,1524228003609,1524228004611,1524228005375,1524228005800,1524228006105,1524228006440,1524228007145,1524228007640,1524228008157,1524228008827,1524228009856,1524228010337,1524228010785,1524228011754,1524228012638,1524228013193,1524228014212,1524228015308],"msecs":[25,247,305,208,197,94,24,19,40,30,32,65,28,27,32,27,20,35,23,211,41,301,33,35,239,26,26,21,24,47,38,39,26,39,49,31,26,398,49,37,41,54,23,269,248,222,236,31,40,20,36,46,41,67,42,47,26,31,31,88,30,310,335]},"weight":10,"maxFails":1,"failTimeout":600,"backup":false,"down":false,"overCounts":{"maxIntegerSize":18446744073709551615,"requestCounter":0,"inBytes":0,"outBytes":0,"1xx":0,"2xx":0,"3xx":0,"4xx":0,"5xx":0}},{"server":"127.0.0.1:8083","requestCounter":49610,"inBytes":10449105399,"outBytes":41258341,"responses":{"1xx":0,"2xx":27629,"3xx":0,"4xx":1,"5xx":21980},"requestMsec":0,"requestMsecs":{"times":[1524227521095,1524227522445,1524227523373,1524227524034,1524227525133,1524227525840,1524227526572,1524227526877,1524227527516,1524227528028,1524227528515,1524227529084,1524227529602,1524227530573,1524227531041,1524227532102,1524227532389,1524227533304,1524227533635,1524227534783,1524227761486,1524227762132,1524227763296,1524227763949,1524227764997,1524227766038,1524227766491,1524227766849,1524227767137,1524227767908,1524227768420,1524227768924,1524227769523,1524227770814,1524227771324,1524227771819,1524227772821,1524227773580,1524227774477,1524227775247,1524227775967,1524228000715,1524228000981,1524228001494,1524228002200,1524228003095,1524228003708,1524228004875,1524228005478,1524228005897,1524228006177,1524228006732,1524228007272,1524228007774,1524228008348,1524228008953,1524228009973,1524228010447,1524228011511,1524228011827,1524228012916,1524228013310,1524228014452],"msecs":[30,233,31,35,212,29,38,21,227,36,34,111,35,54,34,658,21,177,33,240,72,41,232,30,184,182,29,26,32,37,37,39,47,515,38,36,22,26,28,357,30,36,34,254,168,37,27,188,33,28,21,212,39,42,100,37,37,32,647,21,194,34,150]},"responseMsec":0,"responseMsecs":{"times":[1524227521095,1524227522445,1524227523373,1524227524034,1524227525133,1524227525840,1524227526572,1524227526877,1524227527516,1524227528028,1524227528515,1524227529084,1524227529602,1524227530573,1524227531041,1524227532102,1524227532389,1524227533304,1524227533635,1524227534783,1524227761486,1524227762132,1524227763296,1524227763949,1524227764997,1524227766038,1524227766491,1524227766849,1524227767137,1524227767908,1524227768420,1524227768924,1524227769523,1524227770814,1524227771324,1524227771819,1524227772821,1524227773580,1524227774477,1524227775247,1524227775967,1524228000715,1524228000981,1524228001494,1524228002200,1524228003095,1524228003708,1524228004875,1524228005478,1524228005897,1524228006177,1524228006732,1524228007272,1524228007774,1524228008348,1524228008953,1524228009973,1524228010447,1524228011511,1524228011827,1524228012916,1524228013310,1524228014452],"msecs":[29,229,27,30,208,25,32,20,222,30,29,103,29,48,30,653,20,173,29,236,71,37,228,25,180,177,25,25,31,32,31,32,39,511,32,32,21,22,27,353,29,35,33,248,164,33,23,184,29,23,19,206,33,36,92,31,31,27,641,19,190,29,146]},"weight":10,"maxFails":1,"failTimeout":600,"backup":false,"down":false,"overCounts":{"maxIntegerSize":18446744073709551615,"requestCounter":0,"inBytes":0,"outBytes":0,"1xx":0,"2xx":0,"3xx":0,"4xx":0,"5xx":0}},{"server":"127.0.0.1:8084","requestCounter":49609,"inBytes":10450399270,"outBytes":41329605,"responses":{"1xx":0,"2xx":27806,"3xx":0,"4xx":1,"5xx":21802},"requestMsec":0,"requestMsecs":{"times":[1524227522572,1524227523486,1524227524291,1524227525251,1524227526231,1524227526637,1524227527013,1524227527666,1524227528152,1524227528638,1524227529208,1524227529892,1524227530694,1524227531148,1524227532178,1524227532839,1524227533408,1524227533752,1524227534880,1524227761153,1524227761572,1524227762505,1524227763612,1524227764285,1524227765357,1524227766155,1524227766612,1524227766917,1524227767272,1524227768027,1524227768549,1524227769090,1524227769673,1524227770933,1524227771447,1524227771958,1524227772903,1524227773707,1524227774563,1524227775576,1524227776102,1524228000795,1524228001059,1524228001609,1524228002307,1524228003207,1524228004020,1524228004997,1524228005578,1524228005967,1524228006251,1524228006885,1524228007396,1524228007899,1524228008494,1524228009114,1524228010108,1524228010559,1524228011592,1524228012371,1524228013032,1524228013421,1524228014769],"msecs":[38,33,177,35,296,23,29,43,47,45,47,44,39,32,22,377,37,49,54,53,32,297,240,251,277,37,33,27,45,38,48,81,41,39,49,63,34,41,43,239,49,37,33,33,32,46,239,49,30,21,23,69,43,44,56,46,57,29,20,470,38,34,41]},"responseMsec":0,"responseMsecs":{"times":[1524227522572,1524227523486,1524227524291,1524227525251,1524227526231,1524227526637,1524227527013,1524227527666,1524227528152,1524227528638,1524227529208,1524227529892,1524227530694,1524227531148,1524227532178,1524227532839,1524227533408,1524227533752,1524227534880,1524227761153,1524227761572,1524227762505,1524227763612,1524227764285,1524227765357,1524227766155,1524227766612,1524227766917,1524227767272,1524227768027,1524227768549,1524227769090,1524227769673,1524227770933,1524227771447,1524227771958,1524227772903,1524227773707,1524227774563,1524227775576,1524227776102,1524228000795,1524228001059,1524228001609,1524228002307,1524228003207,1524228004020,1524228004997,1524228005578,1524228005967,1524228006251,1524228006885,1524228007396,1524228007899,1524228008494,1524228009114,1524228010108,1524228010559,1524228011592,1524228012371,1524228013032,1524228013421,1524228014769],"msecs":[33,29,173,31,292,22,28,36,40,40,43,38,33,25,21,372,33,45,53,50,31,293,236,246,273,33,29,25,37,33,42,77,31,33,43,58,33,37,41,234,47,36,31,29,28,43,235,44,25,20,22,62,36,38,52,38,52,25,19,465,35,29,40]},"weight":10,"maxFails":1,"failTimeout":600,"backup":false,"down":false,"overCounts":{"maxIntegerSize":18446744073709551615,"requestCounter":0,"inBytes":0,"outBytes":0,"1xx":0,"2xx":0,"3xx":0,"4xx":0,"5xx":0}}]}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать модуль [dpath](https://github.com/akesterson/dpath-python) и передавать "извне" путь к нужному значению:

```
In [126]: import dpath   # pip install dpath

In [127]: path = '/connections/active'

In [128]: active = dpath.util.get(data, path)

In [129]: print(active)
89
```

PS для тех кто пользуется дистрибутивом Anaconda:

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge dpath
```

Comment: Т.е. я могу задать скрипту эти значения не в коде и не в текстовом или ином файле? Мне нужно передать значения примерно вот так "scrypt.py параметр 1 .... параметр n"

Comment: @DenielCherk, да, просто прикрутите к вашему скрипту [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/argparse.html)